# Jump to a specific time in a file?

Tags: lua, vlc

I'm trying to make a VLC script that checks if the "random" button is `on`, and if so when it jumps to a random file, instead of starting at `time=0`, it starts at a random time.

So far, it's looking to me like it should be a playlist script and I can get the duration from the playlist object, but in [this documentation page](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/README.txt) doesn't show how to jump to a specific time from within the Lua script.

How can that be done in Lua?

Comment: I scoured the documentation and the source code and it *seems* it is not possible. You probably should try your luck on the VideoLAN forums http://forum.videolan.org/viewforum.php?f=29.

Comment: This question on the VideoLAN forums, where someone is repeatedly launching VLC with a certain `--start-time` option, seems related: http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=90656

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually, the documentation does say you can do it...though not in so many words.  Here's what it says about the interface for playlist parsers:

```
VLC Lua playlist modules should define two functions:
   * probe(): returns true if we want to handle the playlist in this script
   * parse(): read the incoming data and return playlist item(s)
        Playlist items use the same format as that expected in the
        playlist.add() function (see general lua/README.txt)
```

If you follow through to the description of `playlist.add()` it says the items have a big list of fields you can provide.  There are plenty of choices (`.name`, `.title`, `.artist`, etc.)  But the only required one seems to be `.path`...which is *"the item's full path / URL"*.

There's no explicit mention of where to seek, but one of the parameters you can choose to provide is `.options`, said to be *"a list of VLC options*.  It gives `fullscreen` as an example.  If a parallel to `--fullscreen` works, can other command-line options like `--start-time` and `--stop-time` work as well?

On my system they do, and here's the script!

```
-- randomseek.lua
--
-- A compiled version of this file (.luac) should be put into the proper VLC
-- playlist parsers directory for your system type.  See:
--
--   http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Play_HowTo/Building_Lua_Playlist_Scripts
--
-- The file format is extremely simple and is merely alternating lines of
-- filenames and durations, such as if you had a file "example.randomseek"
-- it might contain:
--
--     foo.mp4
--     3:04
--     bar.mov
--     10:20
--
-- It simply will seek to a random location in the file and play a random
-- amount of the remaining time in the clip.

function probe()
    -- seed the random number since other VLC lua plugins don't seem to
    math.randomseed(os.time())

    -- tell VLC we will handle anything ending in ".randomseek"
    return string.match(vlc.path, ".randomseek$")
end

function parse()
    -- VLC expects us to return a list of items, each item itself a list
    -- of properties
    playlist = {}

    -- I'll assume a well formed input file but obviously you should do
    -- error checking if writing something real
    while true do
       playlist_item = {}

       line = vlc.readline()
       if line == nil then
           break --error handling goes here
       end

       playlist_item.path = line

       line = vlc.readline()
       if line == nil then
           break --error handling goes here
       end

       for _min, _sec in string.gmatch( line, "(%d*):(%d*)" )
           do
               duration = 60 * _min + _sec
           end

       -- math.random with integer argument returns an integer between
       -- one and the number passed in inclusive, VLC uses zero based times
       start_time = math.random(duration) - 1
       stop_time = math.random(start_time, duration - 1)

       -- give the viewer a hint of how long the clip will take
       playlist_item.duration = stop_time - start_time

       -- a playlist item has another list inside of it of options
       playlist_item.options = {}
       table.insert(playlist_item.options, "start-time="..tostring(start_time))
       table.insert(playlist_item.options, "stop-time="..tostring(stop_time))
       table.insert(playlist_item.options, "fullscreen")

       -- add the item to the playlist
       table.insert( playlist, playlist_item )
    end

    return playlist
end
```

Comment: Fun fact: I learned Lua tonight just to solve this unanswered question. :)

Answer (score 5):

Just use this:

```
vlc.var.set(input, "time", time)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a seek method in [common.lua](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/share/lua/modules/common.lua).

Usage examples:

```lua
require 'common'
common.seek(123) -- seeks to 02m03s
common.seek("50%") -- seeks to middle of video
```